# Using Shopify Product Page URL Parameters to Control the Default Size On Page Load (Is This / Something Similar Possible?)

Tags: shopify

Interested in if this is possible?

Even if someone knows of a support page where it describes this process, that would be amazing!

Have been searching a bunch, but no luck.

The goal here is that we have category (collection) pages that might be something like “king sized sheets” – but the products featured on the page contain multiple size variants.

We would like to use a URL parameter (or anything really that accomplishes the same thing) in order to use those links from the collection page >> product page so that the products will load on “king” size when clicked from the “king sized sheets” page.

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to query the variant with the respective size on those collection pages so you can link to them. This is what your collection template probably looks like at the moment:

```
{%- for product in collection.products -%}
  {%- render 'product-item', product: product -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

The `product-item` snippet links to [`product.url`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product#product-url). Which variant is selected on page load is then determined by your product template. In most cases this is done via [`product.selected_or_first_available_variant`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/product#product-selected_or_first_available_variant). The selected variant is based on the URL parameter `variant`. So, for example, if you navigate to

https://myshop.com/products/my-product?variant=123

the product variant with the ID "123" will be selected by default.

The "challenge" now is to change the link of your `product-item` so it links to a specific variant. An basic example would look like this:

```
{%- for product in collection.products -%}
  {%- assign variant = product.variants | where: 'option1', 'king-size' -%}

  {%- render 'product-item', product: product, variant: variant[0] -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

Change `option1` to whatever position your size option has (also change `king-size` to the exact name of the value you want to filter).

Then make sure to replace the `product.url` link with `variant.url`.